# submitPending operation issues in SUP 2.1.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sybase, sup

Hi community experts,
    I am developing an iOS application by referring sybase 2.1.3 documentation. In background i am connecting an iOS device using a native app based on SUP object API's to connect to SUP and SUP connects to SAP backend.
The MBO's are built from SAP functional modules.
In sybase unwired workspace, I have created the MBO with operation and the operation type is "OTHER" and data source specified is SAP. Input / output parameters are selected and code is generated for iOS
The operation flow is like this

```
  // Instantiate header and operation
   ITEM_BAPI_CREATEOperation* createOp = [[ITEM_BAPI_CREATEOperation alloc] init];
      createOp.itemNo  = @"001";

   ITEM_BAPI_HEADEROperation* header = [[ITEM_BAPI_HEADEROperation alloc] init];
      header.itemQTY = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    ITEM_AddComponent * operation = [[[ITEM_AddComponent alloc]init]autorelease];
    [operation addComponentsWithMethod:createOp withHeader:header];
    [operation save];
    [operation submitPending];
```

While executing above operation it gives me the error as itemQty is NaN (not a number) though i am assigning a number value into the header.itemQTY variable and flow of program execution stops by crashing over  [SUPAbstractEnityRBS submitPending]. The same operation is working correctly on android side and giving error on iOS side. Please give me the valuable suggestions.

I will be very thankful if anyone could could suggest me what might be going wrong and how to fix these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your server logs, there should be very valuable information about your issue there. 
This kind of issues usually comes from mismatchs between the mbo defition and the eis model.